# Mechanism of Prediction Readjustment in Supervised Learning and Role of Self-Attention in Sequence Data Relationships

Tags: deep-learning, training, prediction, supervised-learning

In supervised learning, when the prediction deviates significantly from the expectation, how does it "readjust"?
And... LLMs are a subset of deep learning, just as generative AIs are.

Is the use of neural networks constant in all categories? At any point in the context of artificial intelligence, do we not use neural networks?
And Does the concept of self-attention introduced in the paper "Attention is all you need" give it the power to create relationships within sequence data? Wasn't this already being done? (Why was the paper revolutionary in this aspect?)
I need help